# Customized actionbar tab in android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I am trying to change the color of the tab background, indicator color and the text color of my actionbar tab but I can't seem to get it right.

here are some of my relevant code.

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.

    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.

        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.actionBarBG)));
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Unposted")
                .setTabListener(VisitDates.this);

android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Posted")
                .setTabListener(VisitDates.this);

android.app.ActionBar.Tab tab3 = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText("All visits").setTabListener(VisitDates.this);

actionBar.addTab(tab1);
actionBar.addTab(tab2);
actionBar.addTab(tab3);
actionBar.selectTab(tab1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this actionBar theme generator made by Jeff Gilfelt [here](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/). Very useful tool. Just setup your desired design download the files, copy and paste them in the res folder of your project and you're done.

Make sure you first clean your project before building or testing the app.